# How to do training of the Ant Colony used for classification?

Tags: signal-analysis, classification

I'm using the Ant colony for my database of EEG signal for the detection of epileptic seizure. I read [this article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/deb4/9dd86cd75bcdaf02952640cf3f4560b805da.pdf?_ga=1.162217722.771984980.1490472732) and I'm confused. Is this algorithm for training set to genertae rules or just for classification?

[image]

Comment: title says "detection", and line 15 and 17 pretty unambigously say "belongs to class normal or class epeliptic" (including the typo... err... )

Comment: Yes i know but in line 8 " Derive Classification rules by Ant Colony" and as i know this is done during training data that's why i'm confused.

Comment: so, following that, the understanding is that this is both? train and detect?

Comment: Actually this is my question and i want to know is it possible to do training and classification at the same time?